# How do i fix "Error: Cannot find module '@endb/sqlite'"

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, npm, discord.js

I am trying to install a database for my discord bot (using node.js) with sql/sqlite 3, using the database adapter 'endb', however after installing (using npm install) endb, sql, and sqlite3, I receive the error 'cannot find module '@endb/sqlite'.

In the setup for the database, I am using:

```
const Endb = require('endb');
const endb = new Endb('sqlite://my_database_name.sqlite');
```

I have tried many solutions, including deleting the modules and package-lock and reinstalling, as well as trying to install newer/older versions of both node, sqlite, and sqlite3.

Another solution I tried was to `npm i @endb/sqlite`, however that returned a series of errors, too many to list, though i think some of the main ones include:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sqlite3@4.2.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sqlite3@4.2.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Finally, i have looked in the package dependencies and @endb/sqlite is not there. I don't know how to get it to install, and it would be appreciated if someone knew how, i am pretty new to node and npm.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the endb's NPM page and it doesn't look like anyone maintains it. Neither the website nor the github repo for the package exist, and the last update to it happened a year back.

If you are trying to hookup your sqlite3 to node, why not use their official npm module. You can find all the information/tutorial here: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-nodejs/